# How can I train KNN onto Fashion MNIST?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I am trying to train my kNN model onto the fashion MNIST dataset. Here is my code

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
assert X_train.shape == (60000, 28, 28)
assert X_test.shape == (10000, 28, 28)
assert y_train.shape == (60000,)
assert y_test.shape == (10000,)
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)
```

but I I get

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

I have attempted to reshape the arrays as well as flatten these sets. I still get errors and am unable to train the kNN model.

Comment: You need to flatten/reshape the data, and if you do, include all code and all errors you get.

Comment: Where exactly? Please post the full error trace - see how to create a [mre].

Comment: MNIST is an image datase. KNN is traditionally not used on images, however you can get it to work if you structure the data. KNN expects each example to be 1D, but you are passing it 2D information (images). You can get around this by reshaping the data (28,28) into a (1,784) shaped object. Then it will work, although the results may not be good.

Answer (score 0):

Most (virtually all general-purpose) traditional machine learning algorithms expect the data points to be one dimensional vectors. So `X` (and `X_train`, `X_test`), which is a data set comprising of all the data points is expected to be a 2D table of shape `(N, d)` where `N` is the number of data points and `d` is the number of features.

So this is why this error appears.

To overcome this, you need to *flatten* each data point from the 28x28 image/array to an 784-sized vector and stack them all together.

Simply put, this will do the trick:

```py
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], -1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], -1)

assert X_train.shape == (60000, 784)
assert X_test.shape == (10000, 784)
```

---

##### Remark 1

Since I saw `keras` mentioned, I would like to mention that Neural Networks can accept 3D, 4D or potentially even higher dimensional data as input, if you use Convolutional (or similar) layers at the beginning, since they are designed to take advantage of the spatial correlation of the input variables - which is one of the reasons why they are very good in image understanding.

---

##### Remark 2

K-nearest Neighbors assumes your data live in a *metric space* where an element-wise distance function (or metric) makes sense in quantifying the similarity/difference between the data points. The default metric function of k-NN is the Euclidean Distance. In images, we have found that this is not true in practice, which is one of the reasons such algorithms are not that popular for image classification (without hand-crafted features).